# lag while playing video while using opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

so i am using opencv for motion detection, when i use webcam for motion detection the program runs flawlessly but when i use some other video by giving path in *Videocapture()*  function the output lags too much. I know that *waitkey()* is somewhat responsible for framerate but it doesn't seem to be the case this time .what should i do to solve this issue?

this is my code:

```
import cv2
import time
import  os
import time
video = cv2.VideoCapture("videofile.mp4")
_,frame0 = video.read()
frame0 = cv2.cvtColor(frame0,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frame0 = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame0,(3,3),1)
while video.isOpened():
  check, frame = video.read()
  if check == True:
    status = 0


    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),1)
    diff = cv2.absdiff(frame0,gray1)
    

    _,thresh = cv2.threshold(diff,30,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


    dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)

    cascPath = os.path.dirname(cv2.__file__) + "/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    casc1Path = os.path.dirname(cv2.__file__) + "/data/haarcascade_fullbody.xml"
    casc2Path = os.path.dirname(cv2.__file__) + "/data/haarcascade_eye.xml"
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
    body_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(casc1Path)
    face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=5,minSize=(30,30),flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    body = body_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.5,5)
    cnts, res = cv2.findContours(dilated,
                                 cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for (x,y,w,h) in body:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),2)


    for contour in cnts:
         if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 12000:
            continue
         
         (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
         cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
         cv2.putText(frame, 'MOTION DETECTED', (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (255, 249, 0), 2)
    
    for (x ,y ,w ,h) in face:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, 'HUMAN FACE', (x, y-10 ), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        eye_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        eye_color = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        eyes_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(casc2Path)
        eyes = eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(eye_gray)
        for ex,ey,ew,eh in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(eye_color,(ex, ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,0,255),1)
    seconds = time.ctime()
    cv2.putText(frame, 'Time:{}'.format(seconds), (20, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.5, (255, 255, 
    255), 2)
    width =  int(frame.shape[1]/3)
    height= int(frame.shape[0]/3)
    dimension = (width,height)
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, dimension, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    cv2.imshow("video", frame)
  
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q') & 0xFF :
       break
        




    video.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

plz ignore wrong intendation.
THANK YOU IN ANDVANCE.

Comment: set  the frame rate of the output video

Answer (score 0):

primary issue: move all the initializations of cascade classifiers to outside of the loop. it is unreasonable to reload them for every frame or even multiple times per frame (your inner loop).

other issues:

- you should check `isOpened` only once, before reading any frames at all
- the loop needs to be just a `while True:`, not a repeated check for `isOpened`
- if `check` is False from `video.read()`, you should break the loop immediately because the video has ended